# Function call function in C program

Tags: c, windows, date, recursion, time

I have a program like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct {
    const char* dotw;
    int dd,mm,yyyy;
} date;

void indate(date *a);
void outdate(date a);
int datecmp(date a, date b);
int leapyear(int yyyy);
const char* dotw(date a);
date datecal(date a,int n);

int main()
{
    while (1) {
        date a;
        indate(&a);
        printf(dotw(a));
    }
    getch();
}

//print date on screen
void outdate(date a)
{
    printf("\nDay %d Month %d Year %d",a.dd,a.mm,a.yyyy);
}
//compare beetween two date
int datecmp(date a, date b)
{
        if (a.yyyy<b.yyyy||(a.yyyy==b.yyyy&&a.mm<b.mm)||(a.yyyy==b.yyyy&&a.mm==b.mm&&a.dd<b.dd)) return -1;
        else if (a.yyyy==b.yyyy&&a.mm==b.mm&&a.dd==b.dd) return 0;
        return 1;
}
//enter date
void indate(date *a)
{
    int tmp;
    printf("\nEnter Day: ");
    scanf("%d",&tmp);
    (*a).dd=tmp;
    printf("    Month: ");
    scanf("%d",&tmp);
    (*a).mm=tmp;
    printf("     Year: ");
    scanf("%d",&tmp);
    (*a).yyyy=tmp;
}
//Check for leap year
int leapyear(int yyyy)
{
    if (yyyy%4!=0||(yyyy%100==0&&yyyy%400!=0)) return 0;
    return 1;
} 
//day of the week
const char* dotw(date a)
{
    int i=0;
    const char* dayotw[]={"SaturDay","SunDay","MonDay","TuesDay","WednesDay","ThursDay","FriDay","SaturDay"};
    static date mark={"SaturDay",2,8,2014};
    if (datecmp(a,mark)==-1)
    {
        while (datecmp(datecal(a,i),mark) != 0) i++;
        return(dayotw[7-i%7]);
    }
    else
    {
        while (datecmp(datecal(mark,i),a) != 0) i++;
        return (dayotw[i%7]);
    }
}
//Which day is after n day of date a
date datecal(date a,int n)
{
    int i;
    static int Month1[]={0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    static int Month2[]={0,31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if ((a.dd+1>Month1[a.mm]&&!leapyear(a.yyyy))||(a.dd+1>Month2[a.mm]&&leapyear(a.yyyy)))
        {
            if (a.mm+1>12) 
            {
                a.yyyy+=1;
                a.mm=a.dd=1;
            }
            else
            {
                a.mm+=1;
                a.dd=1;
            }
        }
        else a.dd+=1;
    }
    a.dotw=dotw(a); **//if i insert this line, program will error while running program**
    return a;
}
```

Look at end of code, at `a.dotw=dotw(a)`. If I insert that line, the program will error when I run it. But why does it error?

Comment: That's the shortest complete example exhibiting the error? Doubtful. Please read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [the more expansive blog by Matt Gemmel](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: You can make your `datecmp()` function simpler by using the technique: `if (a.yyyy < b.yyyy) return -1; else if (a.yyyy > b.yyyy) return +1; else if (a.mm < b.mm) return -1; else if (a.mm > b.mm) return +1; else if (a.dd < b.dd) return -1; else if (a.dd > b.dd) return +1; else return 0;`

Comment: Your algorithm for determining the day of the week for a given date is not good.  Incrementing or decrementing the date by 1 day at a time until you get to the known date Saturday 2014-08-02 is not good.  There are many far better techniques available.  Even if implemented correctly, your technique will be increasingly slow as dates get further from your reference date.  Also, the 'day' in the day names is not normally capitalized: it should be `Sunday` and not `SunDay`.

Comment: thank you, I have another better code for dotw function.

Answer (score 1):

If you run your code with a debugger, you will see that the offending line is this:

```
Process 89597 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x4598795, 0x0000000100000c06 t`datecmp(a=date at 0x00007fff5f400020, b=date at 0x00007fff5f400038) + 22 at t.c:33, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff5f3ffff8)
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000c06 t`datecmp(a=date at 0x00007fff5f400020, b=date at 0x00007fff5f400038) + 22 at t.c:33
   30   //compare beetween two date
   31   int datecmp(date a, date b)
   32   {
-> 33     if (a.yyyy<b.yyyy||(a.yyyy==b.yyyy&&a.mm<b.mm)||(a.yyyy==b.yyyy&&a.mm==b.mm&&a.dd<b.dd)) return -1;
   34     else if (a.yyyy==b.yyyy&&a.mm==b.mm&&a.dd==b.dd) return 0;
   35     return 1;
   36   }
```

You have a stackoverflow because you are recursively calling `datecal` and `dotw` in lines `97` and `65`. The problem being:

```
dotw (line 65) -> datecal (line 97) -> dotw (line 65) -> datecal (line 97) -> ....
```